# Apache2 server with Varnish www vs non-www domain issue

Tags: apache2, varnish

I have an Ubuntu Apache2 Lamp server that has Varnish and Pound installed for caching sites which all have SSL.

I never had issues on this server before with these sites other then they were running a bit slow so I installed Varnish Cache'ing.

Now however I notice that if I try to go to one of the websites using
example.com the sites do not load
If I type in www.example.com the sites do not load
However if I specifically type out https://www.example.com site sites load.
When I say they are not loading I mean I am presented with an error that says

```
 Error 503 Backend fetch failed
```

So it seems to be a misconfig somewhere? I confirmed my Route53 dns settings have records for www and non www I also confirmed in my apache2 vhost files I have servername www.example.com and serveralias set for the non www of the domain. So what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the varnish server and check the error still occurs.

```
service varnish stop
```

Change the port in apache config to 80  and start apache

```
service apache2 restart
```

and check for error

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```